# How to run Maven with a pom.xml in different location than the project sources

Tags: java, maven

I need to run Maven with a `pom.xml` file located in different directory than the rest of the project.

For example:

```
.  maven-f-sample git:(main) ✗ tree .         
├── etc
│   └── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── example
        │           └── Main.java
        └── resources
```

When I run `mvn` from the root of the project with `mvn compile -f etc/pom.xml` it expects `src` directory in `etc/src`.

I know I can modify source and target directories in `pom.xml` with:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>../src</sourceDirectory>
    <directory>../target</directory>
</build>
```

but since other plugins may rely on other directories than `src` I don't think this is a reliable solution.

Is there a trick to either make Maven use sources located in the same directory from which the command is executed, or to set the project directory with another option, **without modifying the `pom.xml`?**

*In case you are wondering "why"?*

I realise this is not a typical way to use Maven - I need it specifically for [Just](https://just.maciejwalkowiak.com/) that generates custom `pom.xml` in runtime. Right now it creates it in the project directory as `pom.xml.tmp` but ideally it would be created in `/tmp`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to move the file to the "right" directory and just give it a different name? e.g., call it `pom-etc.xml` and build with `mvn compile -f pom-etc.xml`?

Comment: It would but in the actual real use case the pom.xml file is created dynamically in runtime and ideally would be located in /tmp. I realise this is an edge case.

Comment: Maybe you could generate a "master" POM dynamically, which includes every module from tour project. This way, you will be able to set the paths you need.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas this is super neat! It does not though completely solve the problem.

Comment: You have already 2 solutions which are working well - you say the problem might be for plugins, then it should be a problem for plugin and that plugin should have a tag or a way recognizing it - I think it is not Maven Problem.

Answer (score 0):

While it does not comply with [the standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), you can try calling maven like this:

```
mvn verify "-Dbasedir=$PWD" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$PWD"
```

However, this is untested and it is an internal API as noted by Karl Heinz in the comments. Please do not use it and especially do not expect support for this configuration.

That said:
If it doesn't work, please try to comply to the directory layout instead at any cost.

Please also note that some plugins will still not work with this configuration: they might add other directories with different logic.

That said, the solution is (sadly) only: please fix your project. Maybe you can link the file to the base directory?

Comment: I would suggest not to expose internals which are technically available but this exposes those internals to become an public API...

Comment: Does not seem to work. I agree with complying to the directory layout - it is a special use case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would just change the source and target directories (by using the command line parameters). I am not aware of a plugin that goes around this.

Of course, you need to test this a lot because you might break assumptions.